# How can I combine two resource into one project in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have two project, Project1 and Project2, both project have rc file(resource.h),
I want combime two resource into one project, for example, in Project1, I can use two resource: Project1's rc and Project2'2 rc;
how can I do? thanks

Comment: does plain drag and drop work? I remember pulling two .rc files in one project. or, see if you can right click and import existing rc files.

Comment: Have you tried editing the two .rc files **separately** in Visual Studio?  You can then cut/copy/paste dialogs, menus, etc.

Comment: You may do a plain text merge - just copy-paste whatever parts are relevant. Note that merging depends on resource type, e.g. for dialogs you need to copy the dialog definitions, for text strings you need to merge all entries into one table, for version you need to pick whatever version section is relevant (I don't think you can have two version sections in one .rc file).

Comment: In addition, make sure your `resource.h` file is merged, or one included into the other, so that all the resource identifiers are defined. Note that you will probably need to resolve numbering conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by making use of TEXTINCLUDE resource directive mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk.aspx)

Basic idea is to include required rc files in each others rc file, just like we include header files.

For example, in Project1.rc, you can include Project2.rc as shown below.

```
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED

// ... other directives if any

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    // ... other definitions
    "#include ""Project2\\Project2.rc""\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


//... other resource entries


#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#include "Project2\\Project2.rc"

#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Now modify Project2.rc to include Project1.rc, as shown above.

Comment: .rc files contain certain sections that are meant to be there only once, e.g., version, or section with includes for VS resource editor. Not sure what happens when you end up having two copies of those in the same file. Trimming of one of the files may be needed to keep only one copy of those.

Comment: As you know, any RC resource entry will have its own unique ID. If there come two (different) resources having the same ID then resource compiler will report 'duplicate resource' error. No need of trimming is required when the above strategy is followed.

Comment: Well, no, not really. Resource IDs don't just magically appear out of nowhere. They are all defined in resource.h file. So if you simply combine two .rc files, you'll run into certain problems. First, there is no guarantee that resource.h defines the IDs that the newly added .rc file makes use of. Second, you'll need to make sure that the new IDs do not have the same numeric values as the existing ones. Lastly, try including two copies of version info in your combined .rc, and see what happens.

Comment: When Project2.rc is included in Project1.rc, resource.h file of Project2 will also be # included. This is because Project2.rc itself contains the statement #include "resource.h".  To quote Microsoft, “Visual C++ manages a single .RC resource file and a corresponding .H header file as a tightly coupled pair of files.” Hence, a kind of guarantee is there.  As for the second problem, Microsoft promotes the usage of shared resource header files as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk.aspx). To avoid version conflict, it should be kept in a non-shared .RC file.